# Why does Spark use and grab too many memory when shuffle occurred?

Tags: memory, apache-spark, shuffle

I find there is too many memory usage when shuffle occurred in Spark process.

Following figure is memory metric when I use 700MB data and just three rdd.map.
(I use Ganglia as monitoring tool, and show just three nodes of my cluster. x-axis means time-series, y-axis means memory usage)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUn6g.png)

and following figure is also memory metric when I use same data and use three rdd.groupBy, three rdd.flatMap (order : groupBy1->flatMap1->groupBy2->flatMap2->groupBy3->flatMap3)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHqhC.png)

As you can see, all of three node's memory is considerably increased (several GB) even though I use just 700MB data. Indeed I have 8 worker node, and all of 8 worker's memory is considerably increased.

I think the main cause is shuffle since rdd.map has no shuffle but rdd.groupBy has shuffle.

In this situation, I wonder three point below :

1. why is there too many memory usage? (more than 15GB is used when I use 700MB in all of my worker node.)
2. why does it seem that used memory for old shuffle is not removed before Spark application is finished?
3. Is there any way to reduce memory usage or remove memory generated in old shuffle?

P.S. - My environment :

1. cloud platform : MS Azure (8 worker nodes)
2. Spec. of one worker : 8 cores CPU, 16GB RAM
3. Language : Java
4. Spark version : 1.6.2
5. Java version : 1.7(development), 1.8(execution)
6. Run in Spark-standalone (Not use Yarn or Mesos)

Answer (score 0):

In Spark, The operating system will decide if the data can stay in its buffer cache or should it be spilled to DISK. Each map task creates as many shuffle spill files as number of reducers. SPARK doesn't merge and partition shuffle spill files into one big file, which is the case with Apache Hadoop.
Example: If there are 6000 (R) reducers and 2000 (M) map tasks, there will be (M*R) 6000*2000=12 million shuffle files. This is because, in spark, each map task creates as many shuffle spill files as number of reducers. This caused performance degradation.

Please refer to [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Apache-Spark-and-Apache-Hadoop-Map-Reduce) post which very well explains this in detail in continuation to above explanation.

You can also refer to [Optimizing Shuffle Performance in Spark](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~kubitron/courses/cs262a-F13/projects/reports/project16_report.pdf) paper.

~Kedar

Comment: (Writer) @KedarDixit Thanks for your great information. The spark.shuffle.consolidatefiles, one of Spark property which I need, is no longer applied from Spark 1.6.. Umm, Is there any alternative property? When I search at Google about it, but I can't find it.